# How to Compress an image

Tags: java, android, image, compression

So I have an image saved in local storage. This image was taken using camera from the app itself. But the problem is the size of the image is about 3-4 MB. Is there anyway to compress this  image before saving it to my local storage? Currently I am using CameraX to capture the picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Tiny](https://github.com/Sunzxyong/Tiny) library and it works fine. It is easy to use and you can add configuration for compress image.

1.- Add dependency

```
implementation 'com.zxy.android:tiny:1.1.0'
```

2.- Initialization

```
Tiny.getInstance().init(this);
```

3.- Compress

- Create options if you want to add some configuration

  ```
  Tiny.BitmapCompressOptions options = new Tiny.BitmapCompressOptions();
  ```
- Async

  ```
  Tiny.getInstance().source("").asBitmap().withOptions(options).compress(new BitmapCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback(boolean isSuccess, Bitmap bitmap, Throwable t) {
            //return the compressed bitmap object
        }
    });
  ```
- Sync

  ```
  BitmapResult result = Tiny.getInstance().source("").asBitmap().withOptions(options).compressSync();
  ```

For more details -> https://github.com/Sunzxyong/Tiny